# PayTm : Invalid Checksum RespCode : 330

Tags: checksum, paytm

We are forming android hybrid app via Phonegap. Using the PayTm web integration kit.

Checksum is generated properly. But when the form is submitted for the payment **Invalid Checksum ** issue is returned.

Comment: found solution ?

Comment: still, the issue persists. Even following the official doc, one will get this error message. Paytm docs are trash.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.paytm.com/docs/api/initiate-transaction-api/?ref=payments

> NOTE: Create the signature using the body parameter of the request ***in
> the same sequence as you pass in the request***.

example:

> body = {"mid":"MID
> HERE","websiteName":"WEBSTAGING","orderId":"ORDERIDHERE","txnAmount":{"value":"10.00","currency":"INR"},"userInfo":{"custId":"CUSTOMERID_HERE"},"callbackUrl":"https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORDERID",
> "requestType":"Payment"}

## Create json

json_body = body.to_json

#RUBY ON RAILS https://github.com/paytm/Paytm_Ruby_Checksum

```
generated_signature = PaytmChecksum.new.generateSignature(json_body, MERCHANT_KEY_HERE)

curl -X POST 'https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/api/v1/initiateTransaction?mid=MID HERE&orderId=ORDERID_HERE' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"body":{"requestType":"Payment","mid":MID_HERE,"websiteName":"WEBSTAGING","orderId":ORDER_ID_HERE,"txnAmount":{"value":"10.00","currency":"INR"},"userInfo":{"custId":CUSTOMER_ID},"callbackUrl":"https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=ORDER_ID_HERE"},"head":{"signature": generated_signature}}'
```

**As you noted that I pass the body parameter in the same sequence that I used while creating signature(checksum) as in the request body parament.**

Answer (score 0):

i have faced the same issue for more than 2 days. i integrated PAYTM on ionic 4. my mistake was, my "TXN_AMOUNT" is in whole amount. "TXN_AMOUNT" should be in decimal number. e.g 199.33, 152.56.

On the other hand "READ THE PAYTM INTEGRATION GUIDE" carefully. it's actually quite good.
https://developer.paytm.com/docs

Comment: Decimal number should be send in decimal format or string format ? I am facing same issue of invalid checksum and unable to find a solution. On the documentation of Paytm they have sent the TXN_AMOUNT in string.

Answer (score 0):

First try to run with postman
You will get postman collection from paytm just you need to paste key mid there
You will get the response

And please check
The parameter body should be same while creating check sum
Space is not allowed in request body even in json request

Answer (score 0):

one of the reason I got this error was the incorrect URL, I was using the right MID and KEY but yet I was getting checksum invalid error.

Later I found my URL was of UAT environment

Answer (score -1):

Kindly pass the same parameters value in the request which is used while generating the checksum. Also refer the paytm checksum docs available on paytm developer portal.